# How to use TimeInput widget in Django forms?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

TimeInput is not working for the form given below. But SelectDateWidget() works fine. No error is created for current TimeInput() widget.

Suggest the correct way to use TimeInput widget.

**forms.py**

```
class TournmentDetails(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = Tournament
        fields = ('eventname','venue','date','time')

        widgets = {
            'date': forms.SelectDateWidget(
                 empty_label=("Choose Year", "Choose Month", "Choose Day"),
            ),
            'time': forms.TimeInput(format='%H:%M'),
        }
```

**models.py**

```
class Tournament(models.Model):
    eventname = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="None", choices = EVENT_CHOICES)
    venue = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date = models.DateField(max_length=30)
    time = models.TimeField(max_length=30)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working"? Whats the current and expected behaviour?

Comment: Hour and minutes dropdown menu.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default the [TimeInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#timeinput) widget renders as an html input field of type text:

`<input type="text" name="time" id="id_time">`

If, instead, you want to render it as an html input field of [type time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time):

`<input type="time" name="time" id="id_time">`

then in the meta widgets section of your ModelForm class add a type attribute like this:

`'time': forms.TimeInput(attrs={'type': 'time'})`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with TimeInput().
I ended up following [Vitor Freitas' tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2019/01/03/how-to-use-date-picker-with-django.html) and using [Django Tempus Dominus](https://pypi.org/project/django-tempus-dominus/), which includes a Time Picker option.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It is considered best practice to write out the answer here in case the link changes or goes dead.